# How to use callModule from within another module? (Can I use the same id?)

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to use `callModule` from within another module (server side). However, when using `callModule` I need to provide an `id` argument. I would like to be able to pass the same id provided to `outerModule` on to each inner module.

In other words, is there a way to access the `id` a module was called with, from *within* the module?

```
library(shiny)

innerModule1 <- function(input, output, session, someReactiveInput){

  table <- reactive({
    table <- someCode(someReactiveInput())
  })

  return(table)

}

innerModule2 <- function(input, output, session, someOtherReactiveInput){

  table <- reactive({
    table <- someOtherCode(someOtherReactiveInput())
  })

  return(table)

}

outerModule <- function(input, output, session, someReactiveInput, someOtherReactiveInput){

  table <- reactive({

    table1 <- callModule(
      innerModule1,
      id = "hardcodedID",   # I want to use the same id as the one provided to outerModule
      someReactiveInput
    )

    table2 <- callModule(
      innerModule2,
      id = "hardcodedID",   # I want to use the same id as the one provided to outerModule
      someOtherReactiveInput
    )

    table <- someMoreCode(table1(), table2())

  })

  # More code follows here, but let's keep it simple for now

}

ui <- navbarPage( # Some inputs which are not relevant here I think )

server <- function(input, output, session){

  table_A <- callModule(
    outerModule,
    id = "A",
    someReactiveInput_A,
    someOtherReactiveInput_A
  )

  table_B <- callModule(
    outerModule,
    id = "B",
    someReactiveInput_B,
    someOtherReactiveInput_B
  )

  # More code

}
```

I am aware that an alternative would be to pass both tables as inputs to `outerModule`. However, that would require me to use `callModule` on both of my inner modules directly inside the server function. This would create more code duplication (I would have to do it twice, once for each `id`), and would make my already very long server function even longer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the ID inside the module with the `ns` function:

```
session$ns("")
```

yields "ORIGINAL_ID-". Removing the `-` gives your desired ID, that is, you are looking for

```
sub("-", "", session$ns(""))
```

You minimal example was not runnable, see the example below.

```
library(shiny)

innerModule1 <- function(input, output, session, someReactiveInput){

  table <- reactive({
    return(data.frame(col1 = someReactiveInput()))
  })

  return(table)

}

innerModule2 <- function(input, output, session, someOtherReactiveInput){

  table <- reactive({
    return(data.frame(col1 = someOtherReactiveInput()))
  })

  return(table)

}

outerModule <- function(input, output, session, someReactiveInput, someOtherReactiveInput){

  table <- reactive({

    table1 <- callModule(
      innerModule1,
      id = sub("-", "", session$ns("")),
      someReactiveInput
    )

    table2 <- callModule(
      innerModule2,
      id = sub("-", "", session$ns("")),
      someOtherReactiveInput
    )

    return(rbind(table1(), table2()))

  })

  return(table)

}

ui <- fluidPage(title="",
                 numericInput("inputA1", "Input 1", value =1),
                 numericInput("inputA2", "Input 2", value =2),
                 tableOutput("table_A"),
                 tableOutput("table_B"))

  server <- function(input, output, session){

    table_A <- callModule(
      outerModule,
      id = "A",
      reactive({ input$inputA1 }),
      reactive({ input$inputA2 })
    )

    output$table_A <- renderTable({
      data.frame(a=table_A())
    })

    table_B <- callModule(
      outerModule,
      id = "B",
      reactive({ input$inputA1 }),
      reactive({ input$inputA2 })
    )

    output$table_B <- renderTable({
      data.frame(a=table_B())
    })

  }

  shinyApp(ui,server)
```